# Error: identifier "MAXFLOAT" is undefined

Tags: xcode, visual-studio, cuda

I am trying to convert a Xcode project ([link](https://github.com/simonboots/OpenSteerCUDA)) to a VS2008 solution.

In a cuda filetype `.cu`, the term `MAXFLOAT` is used. I am adding the following headers but the error is not resolved.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
```

In the Xcode project, I tried to locate the definition but there is none. Also this term is only used in this file. Is this something specific to Xcode?

Comment: In my humble opinion, this question has nothing to do with CUDA but with the port of a project from VS2008 to Xcode.

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae Thanks for the comment. Your suggestion have resolved my query.

Comment: @ParkYoung-Bae If you want to provide an answer I would upvote.

Comment: @AnastasiyaAsadullayeva: I've taken the liberty of paraphrasing your answer into a community wiki entry. I hope you don't mind too much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`MAXFLOAT` is a non-standard parameter. Use one of the following, portable alternatives:

- In C: use the standard library `FLT_MAX` (defined in [`<float.h>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cfloat/)).
- In C++: use `std::numeric_limits<float>::max` (defined in [`<limits>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max)). You may still use C's `FLT_MAX`, but include [`<cfloat>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cfloat/) instead.